# How to skip the rest in perl as next in awk?

Tags: perl, awk

The `next` command in `awk` will:

> Stop processing the current input  record.   Read
> the  next  input record and start processing over
> with the first pattern in the AWK program.   Upon
> reaching  the  end of the input data, execute any
> END rule(s).

Suppose my perl script is a list of transforming rules, is there such thing in perl that can simulate it, like if I code:

```perl
s/a/A/g;
s/b/B/g; next();
s/c/C/g;
```

the `next?()` will check if a given substitution is successful, then stop processing the rest of the transforming rules, and start over from the first pattern of the transforming rules instead.

What's the best way to achieve so?

Example input:

```
R: waltz
M: 3/4
L: 1/4
K: C
|: E2"C"G | d3"G7" | c2"C"G | F3"F" | E2"C"E | EFG | A3"Dm" | G3"G7" |
| E2"C"G | d3"G7" | c2"C"G | F3"F" | E2"C"G | G"G7"AB | c3"C"- | c3 ||
||d"G7" z/G/ G | BAG | E2"C"G | c3 | A2"F"c | d2"D"c | B3"G" | G3 |
| E2"C"G | d3"G7" | c2"C"G | F3"F" | E2"C"G | G"G7"AB c3"C" | c3 :|
```

The ABC notes, like `E2` `G`, `d3` are handled/replaced last (in a `while /re/gi` loop), while the guitar chords `"C" "Dm" "G7"` etc, are replaced first, then skip the ABC notes replacing.
I tried to use `next if s/".*?"/^$&/g;` to replace the guitar chords part but, all of my ABC notes replacing are skipped, the later while loop was not able to be reached.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're after `next if s/foo/bar/g` - an exact example input/output would help clarify.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about such syntax @jqurious, example input provided in OP now, while the output is skipped. Just remember everything has to be replaced. The "how-to-replace" part will be irrelevant of this question.

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: I realized that the question that I asked and the example input I gave are not the same the problem, thus expected output is irrelevant now, and I'll take your simple answer to my simple question as the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do as a one-liner:

```
perl -lnE 's/a/A/g; next if s/b/B/g; s/c/C/g; say' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will skip the even numbers and print odd numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.30;
use warnings;

my @numbers = 1..20;

for my $number (@numbers){
    next if $number % 2 == 0;
    say $number;
}
```

Comment: The official document on next: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next

Answer (score 1):

I am not `perl`-ninja, but if you have working solution in certain language and want to convert to another, you might find transpiler for that. I managed to unveil existence of `a2p`, which I managed to get by doing `sudo cpanm -S App::a2p`, then I created `program.awk` based at your example namely

```
{gsub(/a/,"A")}
gsub(/b/,"B"){next}
{gsub(/c/,"C")}
{print}
```

as [`gsub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

> returns the number of substitutions made

it will be same as asking *was any replacement made* when using as pattern. Note that it will *not* print lines with `b` as GNU `AWK` is instructed to `next` line, before it is `print`ed. Then I summoned `a2p` following way

```
a2p program.awk > program.pl
```

content of `program.pl` is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';       # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";      # set output record separator

line: while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    s/a/A/g;
    if (s/b/B/g) {
    next line;
    }
    s/c/C/g;
    print $_;
}
```

I tested it using `file.txt` with following content

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

by doing

```
perl program.pl file.txt
```

and getting expected output i.e.

```
AAA
AAC
ACA
ACC
CAA
CAC
CCA
CCC
```

*(tested using perl 5, version 34, subversion 0)*

Comment: Thanks, +1. I learned that I can use `if (s/b/B/g)`.